# I have a bib file.I need to convert that file to excel.Please help me how to read the bib file using java program

Tags: java, bibtex

```
@article{
    IddfeI:000240010,
    Author = {Prdssatt, R. and Robisdfson,and Hladsdvsa, M. and Pedsdfsvzner, E.},
    Title = {{Trendsfds in  - Unidsdffsted , 200df6 (Reprintdsdfsed frdsom MMWR, vol 5336, pg)}}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what you mean by stating *convert that file to excel*? This could mean anything, like whole content in one row or one row per keyword... What **exactly** do you want to have?

Comment: I have a bibtex file with many records in which each record starts with @article. I want each record to be in one row.

Comment: Have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794602/how-to-read-the-contents-of-bib-file-format-using-java). The only answer mentions a few useful libraries, but the question was asked in 2015, so watch out for newer alternatives yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use JabRef.  Open the bib file, then export as XL.

https://www.jabref.org/