# How to read elements of bibTex File with Java?

Tags: java, latex, bibtex

Hey i want to read a bibTex File with Java but i have no clue how to do that? Anyone willingly to help?

Comment: If you google it you find https://github.com/jbibtex/jbibtex. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yeah but im not using maven im using gradle so i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following to read :-

- [JBibTeX](https://github.com/jbibtex/jbibtex)
- [ANTLRv3 Grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7597864/873282)
- [JabRef's BibtexParser.java](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/blob/v_2.11b3/src/main/java/net/sf/jabref/imports/BibtexParser.java)